# Pass parameter from Android to Webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services

I'm having a problem in passing the values from Android to Webservice. The result is always NULL so I think it cannot pass the values.

Here's my code in android (WebserviceCall):

```
 public String syncData(String MethodName) { try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
         .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        SOAP_ACTION = namespace + MethodName;
           request = new SoapObject(namespace, MethodName);     
           request.addProperty("_strInputWhereStatement", "NYX024;"); 
           request.addProperty("_strLicenseKey", "SSD_Key"); 
           SetEnvelope();
            try {              
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);    
                String strSites = envelope.getResponse().toString();
                return strSites;
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here's the code for calling it:

```
_WS = new WebserviceCall();

String _strGetData = _WS.syncData("Android_LoadStaff_Where");       
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"output: " + _strGetData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Here's the permission that I'm using:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Here's the screenshot in my webservice:
[webservice screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vc7DH.png)

When I tried to debug the program its stop here and return a null `String strSites = envelope.getResponse().toString();`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also debug the process on server?
To get the response, i try something like this

```
SoapObject soapObject = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
String response = soapObject.getProperty(0).toString();
```